# MySQL->execute() causes another Query to crash?

Tags: php, mysqli

When I run the following code:

```
$_1= $Var->prepare("SELECT Status FROM UserCompletion WHERE `UserID`=?");
$_1->bind_param('i', $_SESSION['UID']);
$_1->execute();
$metaResults = $_1->result_metadata();
$fields = $metaResults->fetch_fields();
```

I get this error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_row() on a non-object in /var/www/CMS/API/Constants.php on line 17

This query is on a different page to the one which i'm working on.. This query is:

```
$PathLocation = $STD->query("SELECT PathLocation From SiteVariables");
$FilePath = $PathLocation->fetch_row();
```

When I Comment out the `execute();` it stops returning that error; why is me having an execute causing a crash on another page?

**Update**

The `execute();` query is not failing.

```
$_1 = $STD->prepare("SELECT Status FROM UserCompletion WHERE `UserID`=?");
$_1->bind_param('i', $_SESSION['UID']);
$_1->execute();
$metaResults = $_1->result_metadata();
$fields = $metaResults->fetch_fields(); 
#$GetCompletedArray = $GetCompletedResults->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
print_r($fields);
```

Returns:

> ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [name] => Status [orgname] => Status
>   [table] => UserCompletion [orgtable] => UserCompletion [def] => [db]
>   => SLMS [catalog] => def [max_length] => 0 [length] => 1 [charsetnr] => 63 [flags] => 36865 [type] => 3 [decimals] => 0 ) )

and my other query does not fail until the execute is put in place. I know this, because without the query on constants.php, every page the user visits will be blocked.

Comment: Is that contants.php file used as an include perhaps, and executing your new query is causing some variable to be overwritten which is required later?

Comment: @Oldskool Why did you retag this to PDO when the OP is using MySQLI API?

Comment: @AshleySheridan Yes, constants.php is an included file, the query works sucessfully and there is no variable being overwritten

Comment: @DarylGill You are right, I misread. Rolled back, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Perhaps that query is failing? mysqli_query returns false if the query fails. You don't test for that case at all - have you tried seeing if MySQL outputs any error information when running the query?

Comment: @crush The execute(); isn't failing. See my Update

Comment: @user1968541 I'm taking about the query, not the prepared statement. Only reason that $PathLocation would be a non-object is if it wasn't an object - which means the query is failing. Find out why. `print_r(mysqli_error_list());` Also, do you free the result and close the prepared statement when you are finished?

Comment: "Closes a prepared statement. mysqli_stmt_close() also deallocates the statement handle. If the current statement has pending or unread results, `this function cancels them so that the next query can be executed."` http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.close.php If you are using the same connection for both queries, this would be essential. It is not clear from the code provided, though, if this is the case. Are you storing the connection in a SESSION variable and keeping it persistent across the session?

Comment: @crush he is a co developer on a system ive created; the problem is that his prepared statements/ other queries was not properly closed...

Answer (score 0):

From the [MySQLi execute() manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php);

> Note:
>
> When using mysqli_stmt_execute(), **the mysqli_stmt_fetch() function must be used to fetch the data prior to performing any additional queries.**

Your included code isn't doing that, it's only fetching metadata, so the query is most likely leaving an open result set or cursor which makes your second statement fail.